# Eclipse does not deploy jars into WEB-INF/lib directory

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven-2, jsf

To integrate JSF with Spring I have added these lines in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>  
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>  
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And I have added all the spring dependencies using Maven, but when I run the project I receive the following error messages:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
```

When I took a glance at the folder `/WEB-INF/lib` I have found no JAR files, although dependencies are declared in the `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I think that the problem that the JAR's are not packaged with the draft.
Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow! To format code, you just need to indent it with 4 spaces. You can do it either manually or by selecting the code piece and then pressing the `010101` button in message editor toolbar or the `Ctrl+K` key. You don't need to quote code and/or malform the HTML/XML elements :)

Comment: Effectively, I'm new in stackoverflow, I tried to make my code more visible as possible, but I missed the right information:)
thank you for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I have added all the spring dependencies using Maven, but when I run the project I receive the following error messages (...)

How do you run the project? Do you use m2eclipse? How did you create the project? Did you import an existing Maven project into Eclipse?

> When I took a glance at the folder /WEB-INF/lib I have found no JAR files, although dependencies are declared in the pom.xml

The dependencies looks fine but... What `WEB-INF/lib` folder? Where exactly? AFAIK, m2eclipse won't really "deploy" the jars into `WEB-INF/lib` (but it will create a custom class path including them).

> I think that the problem that the JAR's are not packaged with the draft. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

I'm not sure I understood what you mean. What do you get when running `mvn install`? Does the war look ok? Could you actually show your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Thnak you for the reply
regarding maven, I use m2eclipse and when I do mvn: install I receive the message BUILD SUCCESSFUL.
But when I run the web project i receive errors messages indicating that some classes does not exists although they are included in the jars.
So I found that Eclipse does not deploy the dependencies
So I found that Eclipse does not deploy the dependencies
even the jar of the project does not  contains any jars and it has a small size (18 kb)

Comment: @user405458: As I wrote, does the war created by maven (in target) looks ok? That's the first thing to confirm.

Answer (score 10):

eclipse project right click -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add -> Java Build Path Entry will do.

Comment: ... -> Java Build Path Entries -> Maven Build Dependencies

Answer (score 2):

If the library which was not added to lib folder is being developed in the same workspace, I would suggest **to enable the "Utility Module" facet** in project properties of the library project. Sometimes Eclipse doesn't copy a jar into WEB-INF/lib folder even if everything else configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

Maven dependencies are stored at ~/.m2. If you run `mvn install` and deploy directly (with Jetty or Tomcat plugin) there wont be any jar files at WEB-INF/lib.

On the other hand, if you run `mvn package` to build a WAR, the WAR should contain all the required jars to deploy your app. You can uncompress this WAR file with `unzip <file.war>` and check if your jars are there.

As for me, I got this very same error and I noticed I was missing a dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did a maven force update and then installed the build and ran on tomcat as able to find the jars in webapp/libs.

right click on the project choose maven > updateproject > select force update snapshots > OK.

Answer (score 1):

You have update the project by selecting theproject in project exlorer and select
Run Maven->Update Project...

Make sure that after the updated, by selecting the project properties, in the Depluyment assembly you have Maven Dependencies as source linked to WEB-INF as Deploy path. If not, just add it by clicking the Add... button, selecting Java Buid Path Entries, clicking the next button and selecting the Maven Dependences.

Then Eclipse has to deploy the libs in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Both `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` are present in the spring-web package, at least on version 2.5 which is the most common.

Also, make sure you're including the following in your `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
         <version>${your.spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: in fact I'm using Spring 3.0.3 and there is more spring.jar, this file is divided into several modules
I include "org.springframework.Spring-web.jar" ..
but the problem that files jars are not deployed in WEB-INF/lib and I think they are not packaged with the project and it is probably the problem

Answer (score -1):

old question but i had this issue. Fixed by switching to JDK instead of JRE!

Comment: Then there was something else wrong. This 'switch' could not have fixed this.